# Merge multiple array into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array in this format

```
0:["Emp Code", "Reportee Name", "Product", "Target", "Achievement","percentage"]

1:["1000001", "Harry", "Product A ", "116", "110", "94.82758621"]

2:["1000001", "Harry", "Product B", "94", "100", "106.3829787"]

3:["1000001", "Peter", "Product A ", "105", "104", "99.04761905"]

4:["1000001", "Peter", "Product B", "114", "110", "96.49122807"]
```

and want  like this

```
[
"Emp Code":{
       "1000001", 
        "Harry", 
       "Product A ",
        "116", 
       "110",
        "94.82758621"
     },
"Reportee Name":{
       "1000001", 
        "Harry", 
       "Product B ",
        "94", 
       "100",
        "106.3829787"
     },
   ....
]
```

Comment: That's invalid JavaScript. Arrays cannot be objects. Objects need a property and a value.

Comment: your wanted result does not work, because you have only keys or values in an object.

Comment: In the second code example, are you `{`'s and `[`'s the wrong way around?

Comment: Why on earth would you want this and not an array of objects like: `{"Emp Code": val, "Reportee Name": val, "Product": val, "Target": val, "Achievement": val, "percentage": val}`

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. What have you tried so far?

Comment: by the way, where does the last value go? the problem doesnt make much sense

Comment: last value doesn't go anywhere it still there in the above pattern

Comment: It's not wrong I'm getting an array like this after parsing a CSV file          ["Emp Code","Reportee Name","Product","Target","Achievement","percentage"],["1000001","Harry","Product A ","116","110","94.82758621"],["1000001","Harry","Product B","94","100","106.3829787"],["1000001","Peter","Product A ","105","104","99.04761905"],["1000001","Peter","Product B","114","110","96.49122807"],["1000001","Jane","Product A ","91","98","107.6923077"],["1000001","Jane","Product B","99","102","103.030303"],[""]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the first item in the array as keys, and that you want to use data from the position as that key as its value:

```js
const input = [
  ["Emp Code", "Reportee Name", "Product", "Target", "Achievement","percentage"],
  ["1000001", "Harry", "Product A ", "116", "110", "94.82758621"],
  ["1000001", "Harry", "Product B", "94", "100", "106.3829787"],
  ["1000001", "Peter", "Product A ", "105", "104", "99.04761905"],
  ["1000001", "Peter", "Product B", "114", "110", "96.49122807"],
]

const getDataAtPosition = (data, i) => data.map(item => item[i])

const transform = data => data[0].reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
  const thisDataWithTitle = getDataAtPosition(data, i);
  const dataToUse = thisDataWithTitle.slice(1, thisDataWithTitle.length);
  prev[curr] = dataToUse;
  return prev;
}, {})

const test = transform(input)

console.dir(test)
```

Comment: Thank you so much OliverRadini

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want an array of objects with the fist array as keys and the following as values, you could map the sliced values by taking the first row as keys.

```js
var array = [["Emp Code", "Reportee Name", "Product", "Target", "Achievement", "percentage"], ["1000001", "Harry", "Product A ", "116", "110", "94.82758621"], ["1000001", "Harry", "Product B", "94", "100", "106.3829787"], ["1000001", "Peter", "Product A ", "105", "104", "99.04761905"], ["1000001", "Peter", "Product B", "114", "110", "96.49122807"]],
    [keys, ...data] = array,
    result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```